# Testing Svelte components with dynamically imported components in jest (await import)

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, svelte, dynamic-import, testing-library

I'm writing a test in jest for a svelte component which dynamically imports another component. The following snippet is the part where the dynamic import happens.

```js
async function importComponent() {
    if (!dynamicComponent) {
      dynamicComponent= (await import('../Component')).Component;
    }
  }
```

my jest config (in package.json)

```json
"jest": {
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.json",
      }
    },
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.svelte$": [
        "svelte-jester",
        {
          "preprocess": true
        }
      ],
      "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setupTests.ts"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "ts",
      "svelte"
    ]
  }
```

The failing test

```js
it('should open on click', async () => {
  const { getByRole } = render(ComponentUnderTest, { ...dummyProps });
  const loadComponentButton = getByRole('button');

  await fireEvent(loadComponentButton,  new MouseEvent('click', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
  }));
});
```

I tried to solve the problem with babel plugins `"dynamic-import-node"` and/or `"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"`. But the result is the same.

I also tried to use `jest-next-dynamic` (which is used for mocking dynamic imports with the nextjs dynamic import syntax)

I also tried to mock the dynamic import but without any success - or rather I didn't know how to mock the import...

It is not important to me if I actually import the component during the testrun, preload the component or just mock it - the test should just run without throwing errors

Please let me know if I should provide any additional information!

**Update**

The Test fails with the following message:

> Error: You need to run with a version of node that supports ES Modules in the VM API. See https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules.

I'm running Node v16.4.2 btw - I tried the solution described in the link but the result was that all test were failing. Maybe my understanding of how the test is executed is wrong but I run the tests in in the jsdom-environment and not in a node environment so I don't really get the error?

At the moment my goal is to just mock `import()` somehow.

UDPATE:
Workaround suggested by @DavidDalBusco in the comments

> Ultimately I moved the lazy import in a middle / proxy file. In that
> way I can mock the lazy loading part and test my component and on the
> other way can write dedicated tests for my services. –  David Dal
> Busco

Comment: What error do you get when the test fails?

Comment: @juliomalves I just  added the message to the question.

Comment: did you ever found a solution @Apfelbox?

Comment: @DavidDalBusco I switched to @web/test-runner as test runner in combination with sinon and chai - so not really a solution but more of a workaround.

I really liked Jest in the past but this setup was a lot easier to use for some of the newer JS Stuff like dynamic imports.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Ultimately I moved the lazy import in a middle / proxy file. In that way I can mock the lazy loading part and test my component and on the other way can write dedicated tests for my services.

Comment: @DavidDalBusco Thanks! That sounds like a good workaround. I added your comment to the question for future readers.